# MySQL Procedure returning 1 affected row, when it didn't update anything

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, rows-affected

I have the following stored procedure in my `mysql` database:

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE useCount, remainingUses INT DEFAULT 0;

/* Get the current values for the quiz into the variables */
SELECT remaining_uses, use_count INTO remainingUses, useCount FROM quiz_passwords WHERE password_id  = passwordId;

/* Are there remaining uses to consume? */
if (remainingUses > 0) THEN

    UPDATE quiz_passwords SET use_count = (useCount + 1), remaining_uses = (remainingUses - 1) where password_id = passwordId;

END IF;

END
```

As you can see, the update statement should only be executed if the `remainingUses` variable from the initial `select` statement is more than '0'.

However, when I call the procedure `CALL UsePassword(197);`, it returns `Affected rows: 1`.

I don't understand, when my password row with `id = 197` in the database has a value of 'remaining_uses = 0'.

Is there a reason why if would show `Affected rows: 1` in the result?

Is it that if the statement is executed successfully that it returns 1 affected row?  Because technically in this example my UPDATE statement is not being executed.

**Update** Not only is nothing updated, but if I completely remove the update statement it still tells me that there was one affected row!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the end I solved the problem by declaring an OUT variable in my stored procedure and then returning the value by setting it's value after the `SELECT` statement.

```
/* Return the affected rows */
SET affected_rows = ROW_COUNT();
```